# Multiple build commands warning while building - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, build

When I build my iPhone Project in XCode, I'm getting the following warning.

```
[WARN]Warning: Multiple build commands for output file /Users/SilentCoder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myProject-csfqcpziyuvhbiatwwjtkkmwbxwv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myProject.app/car.png
```

I don't understand what does that mean. I have made targets for both iPhone and iPad for my project.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's likely that you have specified the resource to be copied to your bundle/resources *twice*.

(check your copy resource build phases)

Comment: Even though that was that case, I couldn't find the duplicated one in the project navigator. But when I deleted the file from the navigator, the other one appeared and also it was in red font stating that was missing. Thankz for pointing me to the right direction. :-)

Answer (score 12):

Works for me.
Check the list of resources in Project - Target - Build Phases - Copy Bundle Resources Section and remove the resources references.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I create my own first framework following [http://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios] (How to Create a Framework for iOS), appearing the same warning.

And I have no extra resources but two source code files (.h and .m).

Lastly, I found that the .h file appears in two place, one is `Copy Files`, the other is `Copy Header`, and I delete latter one, the warning disappeared

Answer (score 1):

NB: you get the exact same error message in a slightly different situation: if a header file appears twice in Xcode's internal list of header-files to export.

If the affected file has a .h suffix, then ... instead of removing from the "Copy Bundle Resources" phase, you need to remove from the "Copy Headers" phase.

(NB: this ought to be impossible, and XCode SHOULD NOT allow it to happen, but Xcode's handling of header files is terrible (and doesn't adhere to the standards :( ), so it's quite easy to end up with this "duplicated commands for the same header file" problem)